# Running two Jetty servers on the same machine

Tags: java, web-services, soap, gradle, jetty

I've created a Web Application (with JSP) that uses a SOAP server endpoint to do some operations. I run both servers (WebApp and SOAP server) with **gradle jettyEclipseRun**, SOAP server on 8081 port and WebApp on 8080 port. First I run SOAP server, and when I run WebApp it throws the next exception (saying "the address is already in use"):

```
    * Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jettyEclipseRun'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not start the Jetty server.
    at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipseRun.startJetty(JettyEclipseRun.groovy:358)
    at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipseRun.start(JettyEclipseRun.groovy:303)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: La dirección ya se está usando
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipsePluginServer.start(JettyEclipsePluginServer.groovy:67)
    at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipsePluginServer$start$2.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sahlbach.gradle.plugins.jettyEclipse.JettyEclipseRun.startJetty(JettyEclipseRun.groovy:337)
    ... 53 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I've specified ports in both **build.gradle** files. If I run WebApp without running SOAP server, it works (although it doesn't futfill its functions, obviously).
Here my **SOAP server build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath (group: 'com.sahlbach.gradle', name: 'gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin', version: '1.9.+')
    }

}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jettyEclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'


repositories {
   mavenCentral()                                               
}

dependencies {
   compile "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.8"
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}

jettyEclipse.httpPort = 8081
```

Here my **WebApp build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath (group: 'com.sahlbach.gradle', name: 'gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin', version: '1.9.+')
        classpath 'org.gradle.jacobo.plugins:gradle-wsdl-plugin:1.7.6'
        classpath 'org.gradle.jacobo.plugins:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.wsdl'
apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jettyEclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'


repositories {
   mavenCentral()                                               
}

dependencies {
   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
   jaxws "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.8"
   jaxws "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.2.8"
}

//
// See the documentation of this plugin at
// https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-wsdl-plugin
// 

wsdl {
  wsdlFolder = "src/main/wsdl"
  wsimport {
    sourceDestinationDirectory = "src-gen/main/java"
    wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8081/toDoSOAP?wsdl"
  }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += wsdl.wsimport.sourceDestinationDirectory
compileJava.dependsOn wsimport 

//
// Required by XJC because toDoSOAP.xsd is a file
//

System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')

jettyEclipse.httpPort = 8080
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe there's a conflict with other ports.. For example 8443 for ssl connections..

Comment: I've tested various ports, and any works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty uses two ports: one for serving HTTP requests and the other for stopping jetty. Default values are 8080 and 8090. Therefore you should remove from *WebApp* `build.gradle` the property `jettyEclipse.httpPort = 8080` (ports are the default ones) and then add to *SOAP server* `build.gradle` for example:

```
jettyEclipse.httpPort=8081
jettyEclipse.stopPort=8091
```

Additional information on these properties of the gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin can be found here: https://github.com/Khoulaiz/gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin

I have not tried it, but it makes sense to me.

IMHO Jetty `java.net.BindException`should be more expressive by providing information about which is the conflicting port.

Answer (score 3):

The error

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: La dirección ya se está usando
```

aka `The Address Is Already In Use`, means that on startup of Jetty, a Connector you have specified was unable to bind to the specific [`InetSocketAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) (defined as an IP + Port pair).

The most common reason is that something else is already listening on that specific [`InetSocketAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html).